# can you data bind a ListBox with an IEnumerable<type>

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have the following xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrganisationTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Organisations">
            <ListBox Name="Organisation" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrganisationTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding Organisations, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,0,96"/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

and I would like to know if the binding "Organisations" needs to be a List or ICollection or something... Or can it be an IEnumerable. It's just it currently isn't working.

```
class DashboardViewModel
{
    private OrganisationRepository organisationRepository { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        LoadOrganisationSection();
    }

    private async void LoadOrganisationSection()
    {
        organisationRepository = new OrganisationRepository();
        Organisations = await organisationRepository.GetAll();
        OnPropertyChanged("Organisations");
        //LoadBar loadBar = new LoadBar("Logging in");
        //loadBar.ShowLoadBar(this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler tempEvent = PropertyChanged;

        if (tempEvent != null)
        {
            // property changed
            tempEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:://**

```
    public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations
    {
        get
        {
            return new Organisation[] { new Organisation { name = "hi" } };
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

If I do this, I get something back out, so it's the trigger that's not working. any ideas how i'm to do this? when my await on organisationRepository.GetAll() finishes.. I need the onchange to happen and update. doh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the listbox binding to the ItemsSource instead of setting its datacontext.  (assuming your viewmodel is already set as the datacontext of the view)

Comment: Argh, i'll give it a try mate! Thanks for now (have to wait till I get home for this one)

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Organisations, Mode=OneWay}" does not work. doh. but I assume the ienumerable is not the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176778/wp7-difficulties-binding-data-to-listbox-itemssource-wont-refresh I set Organisations = null forcing a propertychanged :)